# How to reload data after flush

Tags: django

I can run `manage.py flush` to purge the database. Now, how do I reload the initial data from the migrations file?

If I run `manage.py migrate unit` I get the following:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: unit
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

My migration file mostly follows the example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/migration-operations/#runpython), except I modified the 0001 file to run the data loads after schema creation. E.g.,

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        # django makemigration generated schema stuff
        ...
        # data creation stuff...
        migrations.RunPython(models_1_create, models_1_reverse),
        migrations.RunPython(models_2_create, models_2_reverse),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, migrations are for modifying a databases schema, with data migrations to modify existing data.

You're better off making that a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/),

or if you really insist on redoing the migration, since you've already flushed the database, why not just drop the database completely and recreate it, then you'll be able to migrate again.

See also [providing initial data with fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures)

Comment: I don't understand why the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-migrations) say to use migrations for inital data loading then? That is, they say don't use fixtures.

Comment: Also, why do the migrations have a reverse function then, if not to roll-back the data and re-apply the data in the migration?

Comment: @TechMedicNYC - You're in a different state to that advice though. You've already applied the migrations to your database so you're not in a position (currently) to do that again, either remake the db or the custom management command

Comment: The reverse function allows you the ability to reset back to a previous database state in the event that an erroneous migration was created